# JS Javascript into a single node / page

Tags: javascript

I have a form that works fine outside of drupal where it called a script  ..../default.js However this does not work inside drupal 6 when i copy the code from ym html/php file.

I have seen this line

```
 drupal_add_js('globals/default.js');
```

Is this all I need to add to get the JS read? I have the php filter in Drupal 6 set to allow pretty much all tags for the administrator.

Comment: Look at [this examples](https://api.drupal.org/comment/120#comment-120). For a specific node take a look at [this](https://drupal.org/node/144880) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61735/include-css-or-javascript-file-for-specific-node-in-drupal-6).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds to me like you're trying to call the `drupal_add_js()` function from within a node edit form (or maybe the body of a form).  Instead of that, just change the body's input filter to HTML (or whatever filter you have that allows `<script>` tags) and call the external JavaScript there as you would in any HTML page.  You don't need to use PHP for that.

I would add that that probably isn't best practice.  Using `drupal_add_js()` is, but you should use `drupal_add_js()` in page templates (e.g., node.tpl.php) or in preprocessor functions (e.g., `hook_preprocess_node()`).

As an aside: be very careful of the PHP input filter, it has major security implications.

Comment: Hi, Thats what I thought I was having troubles getting it to work, but I will give it another go (using the php filter, but it is only allowed for the administrator, then I will look at cross site scripting / injection prevention). Thanks @cdmo